C++ - Custom smart pointer integration - shared_from_this() not working
I am using this library to create custom smart pointers, on which I can track their stackcalls and lifetimes.
This is my code:
#ifndef VIBRANIUM_CORE_VEMEMORY_H
#define VIBRANIUM_CORE_VEMEMORY_H


#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>

#define TRACK_SHARED_PTR_LEAKS 1

#if TRACK_SHARED_PTR_LEAKS
#define B_STACKTRACE_IMPL

#include <mutex>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <xmem/atomic_ref_count.hpp>
#include <xmem/common_control_block.hpp>
#include <xmem/ostream.hpp>
#include <xmem/basic_shared_from.hpp>
#include "xmem/shared_ptr.hpp"

class b_stacktrace_tag;
namespace VE {

    struct free_deleter {
        void operator()(void* ptr) { free(ptr); }
    };

    struct stacktrace {
        static constexpr bool init = true;
        stacktrace(bool init = false) {
            if (init) record();
        }
        xmem::unique_ptr<b_stacktrace_tag, free_deleter> m_trace;
        explicit operator bool() { return !!m_trace; }
        void record();
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const stacktrace& st);
    };

    class MemoryControlBlock : protected xmem::control_block_base<xmem::atomic_ref_count> {
    public:
        using cb_type = MemoryControlBlock;
        struct entry {
            const void* ptr;
            stacktrace trace;
        };
    private:
        std::time_t m_creation_time;
        stacktrace m_creation_trace;
        mutable std::mutex m_mutex;
        std::vector<entry> m_active_strong;
    public:

        MemoryControlBlock()
                : m_creation_time(std::time(nullptr))
                , m_creation_trace(stacktrace::init)
        {}

        const time_t& creation_time() const { return m_creation_time; }
        const stacktrace& creation_trace() const { return m_creation_trace; }
        void log_active_strong(std::ostream& out) const {
            std::lock_guard _l(m_mutex);
            for (auto& ref : m_active_strong) {
                out << ref.ptr << ":\n";
                out << ref.trace << "\n";
            }
        }

        using super = xmem::control_block_base<xmem::atomic_ref_count>;

        void on_new_strong(const void* src) {
            std::lock_guard _l(m_mutex);
            auto& e = m_active_strong.emplace_back();
            e.ptr = src;
            e.trace.record();
        }

        void on_destroy_strong(const void* src) {
            std::lock_guard _l(m_mutex);
            auto f = std::find_if(m_active_strong.begin(), m_active_strong.end(), [&](const entry& e) { return e.ptr == src; });
            m_active_strong.erase(f);
        }

        void on_new_weak(const void* /*src*/) {
            // std::lock_guard _l(m_mutex);
        }

        void on_destroy_weak(const void* /*src*/) {
            // std::lock_guard _l(m_mutex);
        }

        void init_strong(const void* src) noexcept {
            super::init_strong(src);
            on_new_strong(src);
        }

        void inc_strong_ref(const void* src) noexcept {
            super::inc_strong_ref(src);
            on_new_strong(src);
        }
        void dec_strong_ref(const void* src) noexcept {
            on_destroy_strong(src);
            super::dec_strong_ref(src);
        }
        bool inc_strong_ref_nz(const void* src) noexcept {
            if (super::inc_strong_ref_nz(src)) {
                on_new_strong(src);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        using super::strong_ref_count;

        void transfer_strong(const void* dest, const void* src) {
            super::transfer_strong(dest, src);
            on_new_strong(dest);
            on_destroy_strong(src);
        }

        void inc_weak_ref(const void* src) noexcept {
            super::inc_weak_ref(src);
            on_new_weak(src);
        }
        void dec_weak_ref(const void* src) noexcept {
            on_destroy_weak(src);
            super::dec_weak_ref(src);
        }
        void transfer_weak(const void* dest, const void* src) {
            super::transfer_weak(dest, src);
            on_new_weak(dest);
            on_destroy_weak(src);
        }
    };

    using bookkeeping_control_block_factory = xmem::control_block_factory<MemoryControlBlock>;

    template <typename T>
    using shared_ptr = xmem::basic_shared_ptr<MemoryControlBlock, T>;

    template <typename T>
    using weak_ptr = xmem::basic_weak_ptr<MemoryControlBlock, T>;

    template <typename T>
    using enable_shared_from_this = xmem::basic_enable_shared_from_this<MemoryControlBlock, T>;


    template<class T, class U>
    shared_ptr<T> static_pointer_cast(const shared_ptr<U>& r) noexcept
    {
        auto p = static_cast<typename shared_ptr<T>::element_type*>(r.get());
        return shared_ptr<T>{r, p};
    }

    template <class T, class U>
    shared_ptr<T> dynamic_pointer_cast(shared_ptr<U> const& r) noexcept
    {
        if (auto p = dynamic_cast<typename shared_ptr<T>::element_type*>(r.get()))
            return shared_ptr<T>{r, p};
        else
            return shared_ptr<T>{};
    }

    template <typename T, typename... Args>
    [[nodiscard]] shared_ptr<T> make_shared(Args&&... args) {
        return shared_ptr<T>(bookkeeping_control_block_factory::make_resource_cb<T>(std::allocator<char>{}, std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    }




    template <typename T>
    [[nodiscard]] auto make_shared_ptr(T&& t) -> shared_ptr<std::remove_reference_t<T>>
    {
        return xmem::make_shared_ptr(t);
    }
}

#else

#include <memory>

namespace VE
{

using std::shared_ptr;
using std::weak_ptr;
using std::make_shared;
using std::enable_shared_from_this;
using std::static_pointer_cast;
using std::dynamic_pointer_cast;

}
#endif


#endif //VIBRANIUM_CORE_VEMEMORY_H

Than I have this code:
#pragma once

#include "Memory/VEMemory.h"

template <class Base>
class enable_shared_from_base : public VE::enable_shared_from_this<Base>
{
protected:
    template <class Derived>
    VE::shared_ptr<Derived> shared_from_base()
    {
        return VE::static_pointer_cast<Derived>(this->shared_from_this());
    }
};

And I create this class:
namespace VE::Nodes {
class VENode : public enable_shared_from_base<VE::Nodes::VENode> {
        typedef std::set<VE::shared_ptr<VE::Components::VEComponent>> Components;
    
        friend class VE::Components::ComponentManager;
    
    public:
        explicit VENode(VEId veId);
    
        VENode(VENode const &ve_node, VEId veId);
    
        virtual ~VENode();
        virtual void Initialize();
        VE::shared_ptr<Transform> transform;
        void ComponentsPacket(packet_t& packet);
        void SetParent(VE::shared_ptr<VE::Nodes::VENode> parent)
        {
            parent_ = parent;
        }
        VE::shared_ptr<VE::Nodes::VENode> GetParent() { return parent_;}
    
    };
}

This is how I do create the VENode:
    VE::shared_ptr<T> CreateNode(Args&&... args)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<VE::Nodes::VENode, T>::value, "T must be a subclass of VENode");

        auto node = VE::make_shared<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        node->Initialize();
        node->template AddComponent<Transform>();
        return node;
    }

Therefore, I do the following:
void VE::Nodes::VENode::Initialize()
{
    this->guid = VENodeManager->CreateGUID(id_.GetVEMask());
    try {
        auto node = shared_from_this();
        VENodeManager->AddNode(node);
    } catch (const std::bad_weak_ptr& e) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to obtain shared_ptr: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        // Additional handling or fallback
    }
}

In function Initalize(), node is always null. Why is that?
Is there any guide or example written that shows the usage of shared_from_this and enable_shared_from_this?

enable_shared_from_this example.  The important part is to make sure the object is constructed via std::make_shared, which initializes the "shared from this" machinery.

Re: "Is there any guide" -- indeed; chop out code until you have the smallest example you can come up with that compiles and runs and shows the problem. Chances are you'll identify the problem yourself from doing that, but it not, post that code here.

@Eljay there's no need to use std::make_shared, just need to make sure a shared_ptr exists before calling shared_from_this

So, you got very close but didn't reach a [mcve].  Your problem is how the VE::Nodes::VENodes object you call Initialize on is constructed (prior to calling Initialize), which you have failed to share.

"node is always null. Why is that?" -- You have way too much code to demonstrate this. The most obvious simplification is that Initialize should do little more than set the value of node, as in void VE::Nodes::VENode::Initialize() { auto node = shared_from_this(); std::cout << "node's pointer is " << node.get() << "\n"; }. Eliminate most of the other code as well, then add a main function to drive the functionality. Your mission for this question is to demonstrate "node is always null" not "custom smart pointers". Getting rid of the xmem dependency would be great!

@Yakk-AdamNevraumont I have updated the question showing how I do create VENode.

The general design of shared_from_this is that the enable_shared_from_this parent class stores a weak_ptr to itself.  Then when you ask for shared_from_this, it actually just calls .lock() on that weak_ptr.
That weak_ptr in turn gets created when you create a shared pointer wrapping your object -- either in the constructor of shared_ptr<T>(T*), or in the make_shared_ptr function.
Basically, shared_from_this cannot return a shared pointer if you haven't already created one, somewhere in the program.
In the linked library
    using ebf_type = basic_enable_shared_from<control_block_factory>;
    if constexpr (std::is_base_of_v<ebf_type, T>) {
        ebf_type* ebf = ptr;
        ebf->m.cb = cb;
        ebf->m.ptr = ptr;
    }

this appears to be how the weak pointer is injected.  Here, control_block_factory is bookkeeping_control_block_factory, and T is your object type.
So weak-ptr injection occurs when
    using ebf_type = basic_enable_shared_from<bookkeeping_control_block_factory>;
    if constexpr (std::is_base_of_v<ebf_type, T>) {

ie, your T inherits from xmem::basic_enable_shared_from<bookkeeping_control_block_factory> aka xmem::basic_enable_shared_from<xmem::control_block_factory<MemoryControlBlock>>.
Your shared-from-this uses:
template <typename T>
using enable_shared_from_this = xmem::basic_enable_shared_from_this<MemoryControlBlock, T>;

you may already see the problem!  We can expand this xmem template and look at its base class:
template <typename CBF, typename T>
class basic_enable_shared_from_this : public basic_enable_shared_from<CBF>

where CBF == MemoryControlBlock.  So you inherit from xmem::basic_enable_shared_from<MemoryControlBlock> when you use xmem::basic_enable_shared_from_this<MemoryControlBlock, T> in your code.  Meanwhile:
using bookkeeping_control_block_factory = xmem::control_block_factory<MemoryControlBlock>;

and, because bookkeeping_control_block_factory != MemoryControlBlock your type machinery is misaligned.
Try:
template <typename T>
using enable_shared_from_this = xmem::basic_enable_shared_from_this<bookkeeping_control_block_factory, T>;

which may require other fixes (I'm uncertain), but at least the factory itself will know where to put the weak ptr.

Ok but this is in the context of std, however the question is related to custom made integration of smart pointers. Can you elaborate with code example using xmem ?

@Venelin No, but I did debug it in my head, and found a mistake in your now complete code that could explain it.  Hope that helps!
